# Make OSGI bundle require JAR dependency

Tags: maven, jar, dependencies, osgi, bundle

I know that when creating an OSGI Bundle I can declare that it needs other bundles to work correctly (in this situation other bundles need to export things that I will import in mentioned bundle).

But what if I need a jar file for a bundle to work?

Is it possible to write this information in `MANIFEST.MF`? I have the bundle and for some legacy reasons of other bundles that are used my bundle requires usage of a few jar files.

For building this bundle I use maven plugin for creating OSGI bundles (`maven-bundle-plugin`).

Comment: Could you please provide an example in your question? It is hard to understand your use-case and what you want to explain. E.g.: There is Bundle MyBundle and Jar J. I want to embed J in MyBundle.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use normal JARs as dependency of a bundle. You can use only bundles (JARs with OSGI maniifest) as the dependency of a bundle.

You have the following options:

- you embedd such jars into your bundle *(http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html chapter titled "Embedding dependencies")*. This means that that JAR will be inside your bundle, and the manifest will instruct the OSGI container to load the classes from that JAR as well.
- try to find the OSGI version of your dependency jar. You can give a try to [Spring EBR](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/search) or to [ServiceMix bundles](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.servicemix.bundles%22)
- you create a bundle for each such jar with embedding (1. point) and then you add them as imported package or required bundle *(imported package should be favoured)*.

I would prefer the second point, if not found, then the third.